# Bitwise AND operator use

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to analyze some old code to understand what is it doing in case of error. This is the function:

```
error = -11; 
protected String decodeError(int error){   
  StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();   
  for(int j=1; j<ERR_16+1; j=j*2 ){
    if( (error&j)==j ){
      switch(j){
        case ERR_1:
          msg.append("error1");
          break;
        case ERR_4:
          msg.append("error4");
          break;
        case ERR_8:
          msg.append("error8");
          break;
        case ERR_16:
          msg.append("error16");
          break;
      }
    }   
  }   
  return msg.toString(); 
}
ERR_16 = 16; 
ERR_2 = 2; 
ERR_4 = 4; 
...
```

In case of error=-11, the function returns ERR_4. I know that & operator is bitwise AND operator but why someone should use it in this case?

Comment: That function is awful!

Comment: I know :) Unfortunately I need to understand this ugly code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error in binary (2-complement) is:

11111111111111111111111111110101

Because the left bit is a 1 your integer is negative and the second (2) and fourth(8) bit are set to 0, this brings your int to the value -(1+2+8) = -11

AND (&) is also known to be used as a Mask and in your example it would go like this:

Your loop values are:

1,2,4,8,16

11111111111111111111111111110101 & 00000000000000000000000000000001 == 1

11111111111111111111111111110101 & 00000000000000000000000000000010 == 0

11111111111111111111111111110101 & 00000000000000000000000000000100 == 4

11111111111111111111111111110101 & 00000000000000000000000000001000 == 0

11111111111111111111111111110101 & 00000000000000000000000000010000 == 16

Meaning you would get the outputs

error1, error4 and error16

This means you extracted multiple errors out of a single integer

> every Bit stands for another error and with the masking (AND) you check which ones are stored in your integer

Comment: The third one is `11111111111111111111111111110101 & 00000000000000000000000000000100 == 4`, right?

Comment: Thank you so much for explanations. I finally understand it (this ugly function :))

Answer (score 0):

It's used to allow you to store several error flags in a single int; it's more of a C axiom.

The individual `ERR_XX` values represent the bit that is set for the corresponding error flag (eg, ERR_4 = `00000100`). If several bits are set, there are several errors in place, eg `00001100` is ERR_4 and ERR_8.
To check if a bit is set, it's ANDed; `00001100` AND ERR_4 == `00000100`. The for loop goes through the possible ERRs by multiplying by 2 every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is this more understandable?

```
protected String decodeError(int error){   
  StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
  if ((error & ERR_1) != 0)
    msg.append("error1");
  if ((error & ERR_4) != 0)
    msg.append("error4");
  if ((error & ERR_8) != 0)
    msg.append("error8");
  if ((error & ERR_16) != 0)
    msg.append("error16");
  return msg.toString();
}
```

Comment: That won't compile. Because operator precedence defined it to be equivalent to `if (error & (ERR_1 != 0))`, and you can use `&` with an `int` on the left and a `boolean` on the right.

Comment: And there I was thinking that maybe Java was immune to that quirk that c has. Good catch.